# Setting up Google Analytics for a Google Code project, how long until the tracker has been registered?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, google-code

I know this can be a gray area question, and might be migrated to Superuser, but I think that the most people I can find that has done this will be here, due to one of the sites in question being Google Code.

I am trying to set up Google Analytics for my new open source project hosted on google code, but I cannot get the tracker to be noticed by the analytics web page. I've followed the instructions at the bottom of the Administration page on Google code to the letter, which are:

> Anyone may sign up for a free Google Analytics account. Once you have an account:
>   Add a profile for a new domain and specify URL http://code.google.com/
>   Edit the profile that you just created to change its Website URL to http://code.google.com/p/md2html/
>   Paste your Google Analytics profile's Web Property ID below and save changes.
>   About 24 hours after you add your Web Property ID, your profile should begin to indicate that it is receiving data.

However, after doing this, and refreshing the main project web page, checking the HTML source code and found the tracker id there, the analytics web page still says "Tracking not installed".

Has anyone else successfully done this and know what kind of pitfalls I might have encountered?

The reason I'm asking, and not just waiting 24 hours, is that I installed another profile for the blog I set up, and it was registered as "installed" within a minute of doing so. This leads me to think I've done something wrong.

Comment: Yep.  You've done something wrong.  It should notice the tracking very quickly.

Comment: That said you know you won't starting get results for 24 hours..

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question. Yes, I know I won't get any statistical data for 24 hours, but the fact that you say that it should register it at once means I will continue trying to figure out what I did wrong, instead of just waiting for it to fix itself.

Comment: I've looked at the analytics code that google code uses and for the life of me I can't understand how this is supposed to work at all, it seems to be calling functions on objects that cannot possibly exist. I've looked at the javascript samples analytics have on the webpage, and they contain some of the elements, but it looks as though the request to get the actual tracking code is missing.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that the analytics engine actually downloads the web page in question and attempts to locate the javascript code that I am supposed to put in it. Since google code has used its own internal code, which differs a lot, analytics won't find it. I found numerous other questions on the web which all said that Analytics was receiving data, while still listing the site as not having tracking installed. I guess I'll just have to wait and see.